# upgrade wamp from PHP 5.5 to 5.6 - WAMP is yellow

Tags: php, wamp, php-5.6

I followed this procedure 
https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/
to upgrade from PHP 5.5 to 5.6.30 
and restarted WAMP but the icon is staying yellow.
No errors in logs.

I suspect step 12, where it has you update a dozen or so lines in php.ini. Things is, I made no updates because they were already made in step 5. All the other changes it tells me to do are already specified, since this is a duplcate of my 5.5 ini. (maybe this is because the differnece between 5.5 and 5.6 is very small compared to the 5.3 he's using as an example in the tutorial).

Anyway, I've no idea how to troubleshoot what's wrong with WAMP since both apache and php error longs are not reporting anything. (I wiped them first, to have a clear log, but restarting WAMP has not appended anything).

(One caveat: I was not actively using PHP before this, so I have no verification that the 5.5 from which this was upgraded was fully functional.)

What now?

Comment: Install WAMPServer 3.0.6 then upgrade to 3.0.8. Then install any number of versions of PHP using the addons available. See [This post on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) to help with upgrading your old WAMPServer

Comment: See the [backup repo site](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Its easier to see whats available in the ADDON area

Comment: My WAMP v is currently 2.5. It has been running fine for my non-PHP projects. But maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: This may help http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,130697,130701#msg-130701

Comment: It could also be that your Apache while compiled with a compatible compiler for 5.5 is no longer compatible with the compiler version used by 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Search for any references to your old PHP version and replace them with the new PHP version is exatly step.
Remenber Exit WAMP entirely!

You also can check this steps:

-- Download binaries on [php.net](http://php.net/releases/)
   -- Extract all files in a new folder Es: C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/
   -- Copy the wampserver.conf from another php folder (like wamp/bin/php/php5.4/) to the new folder
   -- Rename php.ini-development file to phpForApache.ini (also in wamp/bin/php/php5.4/)
   -- Done ! Exit WAMP entirely after restart WampServer (>Right Mouseclick on trayicon >Exit)

**Note:** You are adding php version 5.6 then you need to copy php5apache2_4.dll from other php folder, too, otherwise the wamp server won't work.